# Process List of entities using completable futures

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, multiprocessing, completable-future

I have a list of entities of type `T`. I also have a functional interface which acts as `Supplier` which has the method to `performTask` on entity and send back the result `R` which looks like:
`R performTask(T entity) throws Exception`.

I want to filter both: the successful results and errors & exceptions coming out of it onto separate maps. The code I wrote here is taking time, Kindly suggest what can be done.

I am looping on the list of entities, then process their completable future one by one, which I think is not the right way to do. Can you all suggest what can be done here ?

```
private void updateResultAndExceptionMaps(List < T > entities, final TaskProcessor < T, R > taskProcessor) {

 ExecutorService executor = createExecutorService();
 Map < T, R > outputMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap < T, R > ());
 Map < T, Exception > errorMap = new ConcurrentHashMap < T, Exception > ();
 try {

  entities.stream()
   .forEach(entity -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
     try {
      return taskProcessor.performTask(entity);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      errorMap.put(entity, (Exception) e.getCause());
      LOG.error("Error processing entity Exception: " + entity, e);
     }
     return null;
    }, executor)
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
     errorMap.put(entity, (Exception) throwable);
     LOG.error("Error processing entity Throwable: " + entity, throwable);
     return null;
    })
    .thenAcceptAsync(R -> outputMap.put(entity, R))
    .join()
   ); // end of for-each 

  LOG.info("outputMap Map -> " + outputMap);
  LOG.info("errorMap Map -> " + errorMap);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  LOG.warn("Error: " + ex, ex);
 } finally {
  executor.shutdown();
 }
}
```

`outputmap` should contain the entity and result, `R`.
`errorMap` should contain entity and `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you iterate over `List` of entities one by one, create `CompletableFuture` object and immediately block iteration because of `join` method which waits until given processor finishes it work or throw exception. You can do that with full multithreading support by converting each entity to `CompletableFuture`, collect all `CompletableFuture` instances and after that wait for all invoking `join` on each.

Below code should do the trick in your case:

```
entities.stream()
    .map(entity -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return taskProcessor.performTask(entity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMap.put(entity, (Exception) e.getCause());
            }
            return null;
        }, executor)
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    errorMap.put(entity, (Exception) throwable);
                    return null;
                })
                .thenAcceptAsync(R -> outputMap.put(entity, R))
    ).collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```

Comment: For some reason, it is still taking the same amount of time to perform task , I suspect for each + join is the culprit, Is there a way we can leverage all Of + get somehow. Sorry I am a novice at this, Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @bitsboy, have you removed `join` invocation after `thenAcceptAsync` method? I've tried it and it worked for me. Could you edit your question with current method implementation? Also, what `createExecutorService` returns? Which class is used and how it is configured?

Comment: Yes i did remove the join() invocation after thenAcceptAysnc, Typically it is the same implementation as you did with out any change , here is the implementation for createExcutor though :    private createExecutorService(){ return Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); }

Comment: Please be noted that it took a 29 minutes to process roughly 1500 entities.

Comment: @bitsboy, you can try with different executors. For example: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` and try to change number of threads.

Comment: Thanks Michal, I am currently trying with 6 and I don't see any bump in performance, May be I should try using forkjoinpool?,, Also I see the execution sequential rather than parallel which I think is the actual culprit

Comment: @bitsboy, Of course, you can try to build `parallelStream` instead of `stream` on `entities` list but probably you have other problems. I made small example which shows that solution I posted worked properly for not blocked `performTask` implementations. Maybe you have deadlock in other methods. Try to use `jvisualvm` tool and monitor app when this method works. You will see how many threads are used and where they are blocking.

Comment: Is there a link for your solution you have posted?

Comment: @bitsboy, I created [gist](https://gist.github.com/ZioberMichal/90498e3eb7f8db47ef29d8f4ff6f4d9c). You can copy and run it. Shows that `11` entities with one-second process task takes 2 seconds with 10 threads. So, it proves that no-blocking tasks works faster in this solution where we `join` threads after collecting all `CompletableFuture`. Hope it will help you with that problem.

Comment: Hmmm. My processEntity involves DB interaction, let me see how it goes. Thank you again for writing it up